# Stupid Invaders sound problem, videos sound changing to French

Tags: stupid-invaders

The first 3 or 4 videos are in English but all a of a sudden the videos start to change into French. It happens with some conversations too.

I've searched the web for hours, but only found one more person with the same exact problem.

What causes this? How can I fix it?

Comment: You can try and learn French!

Comment: @BobR.Shake I did that once with Scribblenauts. There was an incident with a vorpal baguette.

Comment: Je suis parle une petite français. I studied it for 6 years, and i can't stand it anymore, that's why i bothered to post this question. Now i can't enjoy one of my favourite game because i get annoyed too easily with french sound.